# ZeroMQ Asynchronous Client-Server using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, zeromq, python-multithreading, pyzmq

I am trying to adopt the **ZeroMQ asynchronous client-server pattern** described [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:asyncsrv) with **python multiprocessing**. A brief description in the ZeroMQ [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:chapter3#toc24)

It's a `DEALER/ROUTER` for the **client to server frontend communication** and `DEALER/DEALER` for the server backend to the server workers communication. The server **frontend** and **backend** are connected using a `zmq.proxy()`-instance.

Instead of using threads, I want to use `multiprocessing` on the server. But requests from the client do not reach the server workers. However, they do reach the server frontend. And also the backend. But the backend is not able to connect to the server workers.

**How do we generally debug these issues in `pyzmq`?
How to turn on verbose logging for the sockets?**

The python code snippets I am using -

***server.py***

```
import zmq
import time

from multiprocessing import Process


def run(context, worker_id):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    socket.connect("ipc://backend.ipc")
    print(f"Worker {worker_id} started")

    try:
        while True:
            ident, msg = socket.recv_multipart()
            print("Worker received %s from %s" % (msg, "ident"))

            time.sleep(5)

            socket.send_multipart([ident, msg])
            print("Worker sent %s from %s" % (msg, ident))

    except:
        socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    context = zmq.Context()
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5570")

    backend = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    backend.bind("ipc://backend.ipc")

    N_WORKERS = 7
    jobs = []
    try:
        for worker_id in range(N_WORKERS):
            job = Process(target=run, args=(context, worker_id,))
            jobs.append(job)
            job.start()

        zmq.proxy(frontend, backend)

        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

    except:
        frontend.close()
        backend.close()
        context.term()
```

***client.py***

```
import re

import zmq
from uuid import uuid4


if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)

    identity = uuid4()
    socket.identity = identity.encode("ascii")

    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5570")

    poll = zmq.Poller()
    poll.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

    request = {
        "body": "Some request body.",
    }

    socket.send_string(json.dumps(request))

    while True:
        for i in range(5):
            sockets = dict(poll.poll(10))
            if socket in sockets:
                msg = socket.recv()
                print(msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q** : *"How to turn on verbose logging for the sockets?"*

Start using the published native API **`socket_monitor()`** for all relevant details, reported as events arriving from socket<sub>*-(instance)-*</sub>under-monitoring.

---

> **Q** : *"How do we generally debug these issues in `pyzmq`?"*

There is no general strategy on doing this. Having gone into a domain of a **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)**, you will almost always create your own, project-specific, tools for "collecting" & "viewing/interpreting" a time-ordered flow of <sub>*(principally)*</sub> distributed-events.

---

### Last but not least :
 avoid trying to *share* a **`Context()`**-instance,
 the less *"among"* 8 processes

The Art of Zen of Zero strongly advocates to avoid any shape and form of sharing. Here, the one and the very same `Context()`-instance is referenced (*"shared"*) via a **`multiprocessing.Process`**'s process-instantiation call-signature interface, which does not make the inter-process-*"sharing"* work.

One may let each spawned process-instance create it's own `Context()`-instance and use it from inside its private space during its own life-cycle.

Btw, your code ignores any return-codes, documented in the native API, that help you handle ( in worse cases debug post-mortem ) what goes alongside the [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing). The `try: ... except: ... finally:` scaffolding also helps a lot here.

Anyway, the sooner you will learn to stop using the blocking-forms of the `{ .send() | .recv() | .poll() }`-methods, the better your code starts to re-use the actual powers of the ZeroMQ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the tips and links. I missed the shared context. Also will start using the return codes.

Comment: Always welcome @YashuSeth - I am sure you will love the Art of Zero & the engineering mastership of Martin Sustrik, Pieter Hintjens and their teams, at least as much as I started to some 10 years ago. A love that keeps throughout one's whole life.